# How to get a row from SQLite to a model with custom objects?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, object

I am struggling to get a row from SQLite.

Here is my DatabaseHelper snippet:

```
public Expense getExpense(long id) {

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.query(EXPENSE_TABLE_NAME,
                new String[]{EXPENSE_COLUMN_ID, EXPENSE_COLUMN_TYPE, EXPENSE_COLUMN_PERSON_IN_DEBT, EXPENSE_COLUMN_AMOUNT,
                        EXPENSE_COLUMN_DESCRIPTION, EXPENSE_COLUMN_TIMESTAMP, EXPENSE_COLUMN_IS_PAID},
                EXPENSE_COLUMN_ID + "=?",
                new String[]{String.valueOf(id)}, null, null, null, null);

        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.moveToFirst();

        assert cursor != null;
        Expense expense = new Expense(
                cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(EXPENSE_COLUMN_ID)),
  ERROR HERE -> (ExpenseType)cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(EXPENSE_COLUMN_TYPE)),
  ERROR HERE -> (Person)cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(EXPENSE_COLUMN_PERSON_IN_DEBT)),
                cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex(EXPENSE_COLUMN_AMOUNT)),
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(EXPENSE_COLUMN_DESCRIPTION)),
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(EXPENSE_COLUMN_TIMESTAMP)),
                cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(EXPENSE_COLUMN_IS_PAID))); // true for 1

        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        return expense;
    }
```

The constructor in the Expense model looks like this:

```
public Expense(int id, ExpenseType expenseType, Person person, Double amount, String description, String timestamp, int isPaid).
```

I am getting a cast error to the lines I marked with error above

> "Inconvertible type; cannot cast 'java.lang.String' to '
>   com...model.ExpenseType"

how can I make this work? In the database, the objects `expenseType` and `person` are added as Strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With these lines:

```
(ExpenseType)cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(EXPENSE_COLUMN_TYPE)),
(Person)cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(EXPENSE_COLUMN_PERSON_IN_DEBT))
```

you are trying to cast 2 strings to an object of type `ExpenseType` and an object of type `Person` and this can't be done.
You did not post the classes `ExpenseType` and `Person`, so I don't know their constructors, but if their constructors take a string as an argument, maybe you can do this:

```
new ExpenseType(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(EXPENSE_COLUMN_TYPE))),
new Person(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(EXPENSE_COLUMN_PERSON_IN_DEBT)))
```